# How to make dropdown menu automatically positioned

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I made a menu with 1 dropdown-menu using html and css. Then I made it to appear on hover and if client window height is less than 350px it pops up, if more than 350px it drops down.

Now I can't figure out how to make it drop down if user has more window size under dropdown content's parent element and how to make it pop up if user has more window size above dropdown content's parent?
Here's the code:

```js
function dropDownMenu() {
  var dropDown = document.getElementById('header_dropup');
  var scrollPos = window.scrollY
  if (window.onresize && innerHeight < 350) {
    dropDown.style.display = "block";
    dropDown.style.top = "70px";
  } else {
    dropDown.style.display = "block";
    dropDown.style.top = "auto";
  }
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header_menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.header_menu a {
  color: #000000FC;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
}

.header_menu>li {
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.header_menu a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header_menu_li {
  border: none;
  position: relative;
}

.header_menu_li:hover {
  border: none;
}

.header_dropdown {
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -34px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 2;
}

ul li:hover>ul,
ul li ul:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

li.header_dropdown_items {
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

li.header_dropdown_items a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  font-size: 10px;
  opacity: 0.75;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

li.header_dropdown_items a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<body onresize="dropDownMenu()">
  <header class="header">
    <div style="height: 200px; background-color: aqua;"></div>
    <nav>
      <ul class="header_menu">
        <li><a href="#" class="header_menu_li active">Main</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="header_menu_li">Portfolio</a>
          <ul class="header_dropdown" id="header_dropup">
            <li class="header_dropdown_items">
              <a href="#">Item 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header_dropdown_items">
              <a href="#">Item 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header_dropdown_items">
              <a href="#">Item 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header_dropdown_items">
              <a href="#">Item 4</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header_dropdown_items">
              <a href="#">Item 5</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="header_menu_li">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="header_menu_li">Contacts</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
   <div style="height: 200px; background-color: cyan;"></div>
  </header>
</body>
```

**RUN ON FULL PAGE AND HOVER ON "PORTFOLIO" THEN CHANGE YOUR BROWSER HEIGHT TO LESS THAN 350PX, SCROLL DOWN AND HOVER ON "PORTFOLIO" AGAIN**

Here's [example](http://instannelly.com/) you can see what I want (do same steps as described above)

Comment: it's quite weird to change behaviour of a layout based on height tbh. No idea why you need it

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez I found it while using DevTools, then changing the browser's size. 
No need to change layout size, there's need to change dropdown content's position depending on how much space is available (above or under parent element). Hope you understand my thought